# Smallest possible number $|11^x-5^y|$

Tags: number-theory

What is the smallest possible number $|11^x-5^y|$ when $x,y \in \Bbb N$?

I only found when $x=2,y=3$ number $4$.

Comment: It cannot be $0$ or an odd number if $x,y \ge 1$.  Can it be $2$?

Comment: @Henry:  no, because mod $5$ it's $1$ or $-1$

Comment: Is zero a natural number?

Comment: @Joe:  I would guess not in this context; otherwise the problem would be trivial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer is 4. You can observe this based on the following two facts:

1. $11^x$ will always end in a 1 for $x \in \mathbb{N}$
2. $5^y$ will always end in a 5 for $y \in \mathbb{N}$

Because of this, $11^x$ must be at least 4 from $5^y$. Since you have found an $x,y$ pair that yields exactly 4, you have achieved the best possible, and the smallest value is therefore 4.